# Manual maven repository addition

Tags: java, maven

In a spring project I have all the required jars with correct specified version. We have to use Maven but the internet firewall doesn't allow us to download. So my query is can I manually create the folder structures inside .m2/repository folder as per maven recommended  and put the jars there ? I tried this, but maven fails to get the jars from here.
A `AtrifactDescriptorException:Failed to read artifact....` comes out.

Is it possible in some manner, any work around ?

Comment: Can you try http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html, let me know if its helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>x.y</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

then you must place test-1.1.1.jar here

```
.m2/repository
  /x
     /y
       /test
          /1.1.1
             test-1.1.1.jar
```

Comment: Are you sure about this. I did this already. But its not working.

Comment: I tested it before posting. It worked. Check settings.xml localRepository maybe its pointing to some other folder

Comment: @mukund Also do a `re-index` repo to make sure that all manual jars are re-read

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to, you don't have jar in .me directory or jar is corrupted. If you want to use maven in project please open firewall and allow the download it will helps you in future where you will required many jars to be downloaded from maven repo

Answer (score 0):

Specify the proxy configuration in maven settings.xml file, It will download automatically.

```
<proxy>   <id>optional</id>   <active>true</active>   <protocol>http</protocol>   <username>proxyuser</username>   <password>proxypass</password>   <host>proxy.host.net</host>   <port>80</port>   <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts> </proxy>
```

Comment: Even if you place the jar files manully, It will look for **.pom file on that m2 location.